# FileNotFoundException in exec

Tags: gradle

This command here is working as I run it in the command line from `/home/username/workspaces/meditation-new`:

```
jar -uf server/build/libs/server-*.jar mobile-client/build/BOOT-INF
```

But running it with gradle:

```kotlin
doFirst {
    exec {
        executable = 'jar'
        args = [
                'uf',
                "server/build/libs/server-*.jar",
                "mobile-client/build/BOOT-INF"
        ]
    }
}
```

Fails because of

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: server/build/libs/server-*.jar (No such file or directory)
```

Running gradle with the `-i` switch on shows me however, that the command is correctly exectued:

```
Starting process 'command 'jar''. Working directory: /home/username/workspaces/meditation-new Command: jar uf server/build/libs/server-*.jar mobile-client/build/BOOT-INF
Successfully started process 'command 'jar''
java.io.FileNotFoundException: server/build/libs/server-*.jar (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:360)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1681)
:copyWebApp (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.079 secs.
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix like systems the wildcard `*` is expanded by the shell, not by the program to run. Either expand the wildcard yourself, or execute the command via the shell.

Comment: Now it works (and I know I'm still doing it wrong). ^^